# Do INIntent subclasses really require iOS 12?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

When creating an `Intents.intentdefinition` file, the generated Intent subclass source defines the class as:

```
@available(iOS 12.0, macOS 10.16, watchOS 5.0, *) @available(tvOS, unavailable)
@objc(OrderSoupIntent)
public class OrderSoupIntent: INIntent {}
```

But INIntent became available in iOS 10: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inintent

Why is the generated class iOS 12+ only? Can it be iOS 11+?

Comment: Is it happening on `Xcode 12`?

Comment: @Kamran I have tried Xcode 12 and Xcode 11.

Comment: I can not see any issue on `Xcode 11.5`. Not sure about higher versions.

Comment: @Kamran In Xcode 11.5 what is the `@available` attribute that appears on your files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that custom intents was introduced in iOS 12. While I couldn't find in the SiriKit documentation, here's the WWDC video introducing the feature: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211

> Siri Shortcuts are a powerful new feature in iOS 12 that allow your app to expose its functionality to Siri.